# 2-way binding of textArea in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of question that user has to answer.For that a have prepared a form.

The html form is

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="question in questions.data.Question" > 
      <div class="item item-divider">
         {{question.text}}
  </div>
    <label class="item item-input" ng-if="question.type =='comment'">
      <textarea placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
   </label>
 </div>
```

now my json string is

```
{
    "sucess": true,
    "message": "record(s) fetched sucessfully",
    "data": {
        "Question": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "text": "how was it?",
                "type": "comment"
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "text": "how was it?",
                "type": "comment"
            }
        ]
    }
 }
```

now when user submit the form I should get the comment user has posted of all the question.

Comment: What is your question? What isn't working? What have you tried?

Comment: I want the answer that user has posted for all the question when click on the submit button.

Answer (score 6):

I am not angular expert, but I think you need to add ng-model to the textarea element.

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="question in questions.data.Question" > 
      <div class="item item-divider">
          {{question.text}}
      </div>
      <label class="item item-input" ng-if="question.type =='comment'">
          <textarea placeholder="Comments" ng-model="question.comments"></textarea>
      </label>
 </div>
```

And, you also need to add 'comments' field to each comment type question. Example:

```
        {
            "id": "6",
            "text": "how was it?",
            "type": "comment",
            "comments": ""

        }
```

Note that you may not need to add "comments" field if there is a 'force add field' flag for angularjs that i'm not aware of.

Comment: but want to post it in other model not in same service

Comment: what does this submit button do? submits the form? Have you added ng-submit directive to that form? if you want to submit all comments that user has posted, you should just send the models in the function in your controller that ng-submit calls. The models are updated automatically when the DOM element you put ng-model in changes.

Comment: no on ng-clik of button i have called a function passing the model

Comment: what do you do in the method of ng-click? Do you want to pass this information to an another controller in the same page? If so, how do you open/populate this controller?

Answer (score 6):

You have to bind ng-model to the textarea, it works even if you don't have the "answer" variable in your initial json data. I have added a button for demo purpose. Full example on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fzJ6m/4/)

```
<div id="qApp" ng-controller="qAppCntrl">
 <div class="list" ng-repeat="question in questions.data.Question track by $index" > 
  <div class="item item-divider">
     {{question.text}}
  </div>
  <label class="item item-input" ng-if="question.type =='comment'">
    <textarea placeholder="Comments" ng-model="question.answer"></textarea>
  </label>
 </div>
 <button ng-click="submit()">Post</button>
</div>
```