# unable to get the model value in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of question that user has to answer.For that a have prepared a form.
I get the number many comment textarea.Now whatever i type on first box i get in second.

The html form is

```
 <form>
    <div class="list" ng-repeat="question in questions.data.Question" > 
          <div class="item item-divider">
             {{question.text}}
      </div>
        <label class="item item-input" ng-if="question.type =='comment'">
          <textarea placeholder="Comments" ng-model=answer.comments></textarea>
       </label>
     </div>
      <button type="submit" class="button button-positive" ng-click="feedback()"> Submit</button>                  
  <form>
```

In my contoller i have define

```
$scope.answer=t={};
   $scope.feedback=function(){
    var a =t;
    console.log(a);
  }
```

The other problem is i want the question id and its comment be posted so i have defined the variable $scope.answer so that i get it in array format like the one below.But i get error in the console

```
answer=[
         {
        "questionid": "6"
        "comments": "blah blah"
        },
       {
        "questionid":7
         "comments":"blah blah"
       }]
```

Comment: Duplicate question, asked by another user and was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079505/2-way-binding-of-textarea-in-angular-js/24081420#24081420)